# MVC JavaFx methods

Tags: model-view-controller, methods, view, javafx, program-entry-point

if I want to add for example the mouse event "setOnMouseEntered" to my code and I already have a viewer, controller, model and main. Where do I put this method in? 
Because if I search for examples, this methos is written in the start-method. In my case it would be in the main class? Actually have kind of a scene styler in the viewer. 
Thanks!

Comment: There are many varieties of MVC and the answer to this depends on which flavor you use (and still may vary even then). You should register handlers either in the view or in the controller (because the model knows nothing about the view); but either of those options is widely used.

Answer (score 0):

do you search for something like this?

https://github.com/StefanHeimberg/javafx8-spielwiese/tree/master/example-fullscreen-fade/src/main/java/example/menubar.

in the menubar.fxml (VIEW) i used the onAction="#handleImage2LongRunningAction" and fx:controller="example.menubar.MenubarPresenter" (CONTROLLER)

then on the presenter i called some service (MODEL / Business Logic)...